# ASP.Net MVC5 Use windows authentication to authenticate user and run application using a service account

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, windows-authentication

I use windows authentication to authenticate the user and the application is run by another user, using this link http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-using-windows-authentication-with-minimal-permissions-granted-to-disk , I got the application on the back end to be run by a service account.
 When I use User.Identity.name I get the user who is running the application and not the user who was authenticate. How can I get the user identity of the user who was authenticated?

Comment: Is anonymous authentication realy disabled? Sounds like it's still on.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments below the article:

Request["LOGON_USER"]  returns the original user.